# Using TArray.Copy with generics arrays

Tags: arrays, delphi, generics, delphi-xe7

I'm trying to copy all the items from a generic array to a new one using [`TArray.Copy`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Generics.Collections.TArray.Copy) (Note: In Delphi XE7 the function has no documentation).

```
class procedure Copy<T>(const Source, Destination: array of T; SourceIndex, DestIndex, Count: NativeInt); overload; static;
class procedure Copy<T>(const Source, Destination: array of T; Count: NativeInt); overload; static;
```

The Source array turns into a zero filled array after executing the function:

```
var
  Source : TArray<Integer>;
  Destination : TArray<Integer>;
begin
  Source := [10, 20];
  SetLength(Destination, Length(Source));

  //here Source is [10, 20]

  TArray.Copy<Integer>(Source, Destination, 0, 0, Length(Source));

  //here Source is [0, 0]
end;
```

Why is it changing the Source array?

Comment: Can't reproduce in Delphi 10.

Comment: Are you inspecting the source array contents in Delphi IDE or in code? If in Delphi IDE then the result for this might be code optimization since after the array copy procedure is made source array no longer need to exist.

Comment: @SilverWarior: Good point, unfortunately it also happens when using the array values after checking them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TArray.Copy` was broken in XE7 because someone confused the parameters of `System.Move`:

[RSP-9763: TArray.Copy copies from destination to source for unmanaged types](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-9763)

[RSP-9887: TArray.Copy is broken in multiple ways](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-9887)

FWIW, for your scenario, it does not need `TArray.Copy` - `System.Copy` can handle copying arrays if the copied range starts from the beginning. If you want to copy the entire content, you can even omit the second and third parameter and simply call:

```
Destination := Copy(Source);
```

Comment: Thanks for informations, System.Copy works fine!